# bash: get literal parameters passed to a script and execute them as a command

Tags: bash, shell, mercurial

### Goal and context

I am writing a bash script (called `foreach_repo`) that should execute the passed parameters as a shell command, e.g.:

```
 foreach_repo hg status
```

should execute the command `hg status`. (It does this on a complicated nested structure of repositories, I have no control over this structure, but I need to batch operate on them quite often).

This type of command is similar to `sudo` and other 'higher-order' commands; for example `sudo hg status` would in turn execute `hg status` with superuser rights.

Internally, my script does the following (given a feed of repository paths on stdin, created by another part of the script - irrelevant to this question):

```
while read repo do
    container="$repo/.."
    cd $base/$container
    $@
done
```

Where `$@` is meant to interpret the passed arguments as the command to be executed in the repository.

### Execution

This approach works fine for simple commands, for example

```
foreach_repo hg status
```

will correctly return the status list of every repository in the structure. However, more complicated commands (with escapes, quotes ...) are messed up. For example, when I try

```
foreach_repo hg commit -m "some message"
```

I get

```
abort: message: no such file or directory
```

Because the quotes were stripped off, the actual command executed was:

```
hg commit -m some message
```

### Attempted solutions

Manually escaping the quotes, or the entire command to be passed, has no effect, neither has using `$*` instead of `$@`. However, commands like `sudo` can handle this type of situation, that is:

```
sudo hg commit -m "some message"
```

would actually (and correctly) execute

```
hg commit -m "some message"
```

How can I accomplish the same behavior?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are on the right track, and almost got it. You just need to use `"$@"` instead of `$@`.

Here's a summary of what `$*` and `$@` do, with and without quotes:

- `$*` and `$@` paste in the positional arguments, then tokenise them (using `$IFS`) into separate strings.
- `"$*"` pastes in the positional arguments as one string, with the first character of `$IFS` (usually a space) inserted between each.
- `"$@"` pastes in the positional arguments, as a string for each argument.

Examples:

```
$ set foo bar "foo bar:baz"
$ printf "%s\n" $*
foo
bar
foo
bar:baz
$ printf "%s\n" $@
foo
bar
foo
bar:baz
$ printf "%s\n" "$*"
foo bar foo bar:baz
$ printf "%s\n" "$@"
foo
bar
foo bar:baz
```

Here's what changes when you set `$IFS`:

```
$ IFS=:
$ printf "%s\n" $*
foo
bar
foo bar
baz
$ printf "%s\n" $@
foo
bar
foo bar
baz
$ printf "%s\n" "$*"
foo:bar:foo bar:baz
$ printf "%s\n" "$@"
foo
bar
foo bar:baz
```