# bash function return status

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a function

```
function f() {
  command 1
  command 2
  command 3
  command 4
}
```

I want function f() to somehow tell me there is an error if any of the 4 commands fails.

I also don't want to `set -e`. I want four commands all run, even if one fails.

How do I do that? Sorry for the newbie question -- I am quite new to bash scripting.

Comment: this link also helpful : [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32990525/check-all-commands-exit-code-within-a-bash-script/32990797#32990797](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32990525/check-all-commands-exit-code-within-a-bash-script/32990797#32990797)

Comment: @user1261959 This is basically what I am doing in my answer. I did not found an existing answer, otherwise I would have linked to it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand what you're asking correctly, you can do this:

```
f() {
  err=""
  command 1 || err=${err}1
  command 2 || err=${err}2
  command 3 || err=${err}3
  command 4 || err=${err}4
  # do something with $err to report the error
}
```

Of course, instead of using a variable you could simply put echo commands after the `||` if all you need to do is print an error message:

```
f() {
  command 1 || echo "command 1 failed" >&2
  command 2 || echo "command 2 failed" >&2
  command 3 || echo "command 3 failed" >&2
  command 4 || echo "command 4 failed" >&2
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Take advantage of [`"$@"`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18333134/124319) and write a higher-order function:

```
function warner () { "$@" || echo "Error when executing '$@'" >&2; }
```

Then:

```
warner command 1
warner command 2
warner command 3
warner command 4
```

Test:

```
$ warner git status
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
Error when executing 'git status'

$ warner true
```

As @user1261959 [found out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33338007/bash-function-return-status/33338084#comment54482508_33338007), this is the same approach as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32990525/check-all-commands-exit-code-within-a-bash-script/32990797#32990797).

Comment: Well the problem is command 1 - command n still need to be run regardless whether something fails in the middle. It's just nice to know that something fails.

Comment: @CodeNoob Sorry for the misunderstanding, totally rewrote the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the exit flag of any of your commands after they run by checking the variable `$?`.If it returns 0 usually everything went well otherwise it means an error occurred. You can make your function return a flag to the caller by using the keyword `return`